# Copy all the bundle resources to a separate folder inside the Documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsbundle, nsdocumentdirectory

What is the correct way of copying **all the files** contained in the Bundle (not the `[NSBundle mainBundle]`) and putting them to a newly created directory inside the `Documents` directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Bundle"? Any `Bundle` object?

Comment: Bundle created with CocoaPods. It can be any bundle.

Comment: I just added an answer for how to do it at runtime, but I'm guessing that you want to copy the bundle resources as a Build Phase, pre-compilation, right?

Comment: No, at runtime .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the items one by one, it's fairly straightforward.

```
let bundle: Bundle = ... // Whatever bundle you want to copy from
    guard let resourceURL = bundle.resourceURL else { return }
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let documentsDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                 in: .userDomainMask,
                                                 appropriateFor: nil,
                                                 create: false)
    let destination = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("BundleResourcesCopy", isDirectory: true)

    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        assert(isDirectory.boolValue)
    } else {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destination, withIntermediateDirectories: false)
    }

    let resources = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: resourceURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    for resource in resources {
        print("Copy \(resource) to \(destination.appendingPathComponent(resource.lastPathComponent))")
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: resource,
                                 to: destination.appendingPathComponent(resource.lastPathComponent))
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Depending on the size of the bundle this could take some time to perform, so you may want to perform this on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to actually copy all the files and folders one-by-one. I needed Objective-C solution, but I could use your as a starting point and rewrite in Objective-C.